# Aggregation value error in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, sense

I am trying to create a *Date Histogram* and aggregate a particular field to find the *maximum* value which is of **long** type in mapping from my ealsticsearch, but i get the result in **floating point** number, 
for example :
Instead of getting **31032832** am getting **3.1032832E7**

However am able to get **31032832** properly when i query my elasticsearch index through *chrome plugin sense*.

Comment: 31032832 = 3.1032832E7. So what is the problem?

Comment: Can you share the query you're running against Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the issue! it was giving me double value after aggregation because of this:

[image]

while accessing i called `myResult.getMax().longValue()` which solved my problem.